# Issue in deploying Lead Flexipage with Einstein IQ component

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, cicd

We are using Bitbucket Pipelines to do CI/CD with Salesforce using a Sandbox development model and the Salesforce CLI to retrieve declarative changes and to deploy.

We have recently enabled Einstein Lead Scoring in Production and have obviously added the IQ component to the Lightning record page.  The issue being now, when we go through the beginning of our CI/CD process, step one is to deploy to a Dev Pro sandbox and run all the Apex tests.

The issue is that, deploy fails because Lead scoring is not enabled in the sandbox, nor can it be as there is not any data.
I can easily not track the flexipage in version control, but it is referenced in the Lead object's metadata as an actionOverride.

I am really kinda stuck here.  As of right now, I commented out the `<actionOverrides>` section in the Lead.object metadata and leave the flexipage out of version control, but I really want to not have do all this everytime.

Any suggestions on how to handle the Lead Iqscore component on flexipages would be greatly appreciated.